# Prestige Mode in Prestige 15? What happens?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I'm level 80 Prestige 15 on PS3. I'm able to go to Prestige-Mode (after the new update). What's going to happen?

Comment: Do it and tell us :-)

Comment: haha^^ I do not trust :)

Comment: After that, you will need to leave your couch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinity Ward will allow to let us Prestige until Prestige 20.
But at the moment this isn't possible (maybe next Update will unlock the last 5 Prestiges).

If I Prestige NOW, I will get Prestige 15 again and start from level 1 (Can get a Prestige Token doing that) but thats everything.

Comment: I really don't see how this differs from my answer.

Comment: u didnt tell me, that I will start again from lvl 1 Prestige 15.

Comment: Um, sir, every-time you prestige you always restart from level 1. Its a given...

Comment: "Nothing happens more or less then a normal prestige." Is what I said...

Comment: No no no.. Its clear that I start from level 1.. But that I start from Level 1 from the same Prestige (15) I Prestiged (15) isnt normal.. thats what u wasn't able to tell me and the link also doesn't gives any Informations ;)

Answer (score 4):

I can assume it would be the same as any of the other times you prestige.

The max level simply means you reached the highest possible rank you can.

[Check this link](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Prestige_Mode) here for more information on Prestiging.

So simply: **Nothing happens more or less then a normal prestige.**

Comment: I know it now, read my answer

Comment: Where is your answer exactly?

Comment: sry, I was writing the answer, then I had to go anywhere.. Answered just now

Answer (score 0):

That is when you unlock reset profile option and work back up the ladder again.